# How to navigate through a JSON object which is nested 'N' number of times like a parent and child in C#

Tags: c#, json, nested, parent

Example of JSON:

How can I go and get values of Gum, and loop it through as many times it is present. Basically I want to get the Gum section from the json and get all the corresponding values in that section. If another Gum is there I should then loop to it in next iteration after saving the values of the first.

Also, I should mark the first Gum section with a variable and save a value for it. (As Parent Gum). The variables with are having parent gum as empty will be considered as Child.

```
{
   "Response": {
      "ResponseAttributes": [
         {
            "@Key": "MessagePurpose",
            "#text": "PROD"
         },
         {
            "@Key": "SHIP_TO_COUNTRY",
            "#text": "BR"
         },
         {
            "@Key": "SourcePlan",
            "#text": "LEGACY"
         }
      ],
      "Gums": {
         "Gum": {
            "Level": "1",
            "TranFro": {
               "@type": "3PL",
               "#text": "BFC"
            },
            "TranTo": {
               "@type": "CUSTOMER",
               "#text": "CUST"
            },
            "Trail": "G",
            "FSBD": "2022-02-17T00:00:00",
            "FABD": "2022-02-17T00:00:00",
            "IsNorth": "N",
            "Gum": {
               "Level": "2",
               "TranFro": {
                  "@type": "3PL",
                  "#text": "BMC"
               },
               "TranTo": {
                  "@type": "3PL",
                  "#text": "BFC"
               },
               "Trail": "G",
               "FSBD": "2022-02-17T00:00:00",
               "FABD": "2022-02-17T00:00:00",
               "IsNorth": "N",
               "Gum": {
                  "Level": "3",
                  "TranFro": {
                     "@type": "ODM",
                     "#text": "BR1X"
                  },
                  "TranTo": {
                     "@type": "3PL",
                     "#text": "BMC"
                  },
                  "Trail": "G",
                  "FSBD": "2022-02-17T00:00:00",
                  "FABD": "2022-02-17T00:00:00",
                  "IsNorth": "N",
                  "Parts": [],
                  "Services": [],
                  "Attributes": [
                     {
                        "@Key": "Bear",
                        "#text": "BMC"
                     },
                     {
                        "@Key": "code",
                        "#text": "BMC"
                     },
                     {
                        "@Key": "PHJ",
                        "#text": "BMC"
                     },
                     {
                        "@Key": "NewDir",
                        "#text": "N"
                     },
                     {
                        "@Key": "RotType",
                        "#text": "SINGLE"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "Parts": [],
               "Services": [],
               "Attributes": [
                  {
                     "@Key": "Bear",
                     "#text": "BFC"
                  },
                  {
                     "@Key": "code",
                     "#text": "BFC"
                  },
                  {
                     "@Key": "PHJ",
                     "#text": "BFC"
                  },
                  {
                     "@Key": "RotType",
                     "#text": "SINGLE"
                  },
                  {
                     "@Key": "NewDir",
                     "#text": "N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Parts": [],
            "Services": [],
            "Attributes": [
               {
                  "@Key": "RotType",
                  "#text": "SINGLE"
               },
               {
                  "@Key": "NewDir",
                  "#text": "Y"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried serializing it but I get to navigate through the first Gum only - Level-1.
The loops break out then.
`foreach (var Gums in rpJsonObject.Response.Gums)`
`{`
`//After one Gum it comes out. I know since I'm not going inside the child`
`}`

Comment: Hard to understand what do you want. Pls post a json you would like to get

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want to have at the end of your code. Is it just all the `Gum` objects in a list, with those who have a parent including a parent reference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.